# How to fix "Circular view path" exception error? - Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

//I was shown this error in the log when I ran this code ->

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Circular view path [Students]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/Students] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)] with root cause "

```java
//Controller class

import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class StudnetController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping(path = "/Students")
    public List<Student> getAllStudent(){

    return studentService.getStudent();
        
    }

}
```

```java
//service class


@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepo studentRepo;

    public List<Student> getStudent(){

        return studentRepo.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: Don't know if this is causing your issue, but you'll need a `@ResponseBody` or `@RestController` annotation if you intend for the list of students to be the response body of that request.

Comment: You've mis-typed `Student` in `StudnetController`. Does it help if you fix this typo?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I Changed the `@Controller` to `@RestController` and solved the issue.

As @Knox mentioned in the comments, You either have to use `@ResponseBody`+`@Controller` or just use `@RestController`.

As the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) say:

> @RestController is A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-controller-and-restcontroller-annotation-in-spring/#:%7E:text=%40RestController-,%40Controller%20is%20used%20to%20mark%20classes%20as%20Spring%20MVC%20Controller,specialized%20version%20of%20%40Component%20annotation.).

Comment: Okay, thank you for solving the code problem.